# Rails Routing: what is the difference between :conditions and :requirements in routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When should I use :conditions or :requirements in rails routing?

Here are two examples:

:conditions

```
map.connect "/foo/:view/:permalink", :controller => "foo",
    :action => "show", :view => /plain|fancy/,
    :permalink => /[-a-z0-9]+/,
    :conditions => { :method => :get }
end
```

:requirements

```
 map.connect 'posts/index/:page',
            :controller => 'posts',
            :action => 'index',
            :requirements => {:page => /\d+/ },
            :page => nil
 end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only option `:conditions` takes is `:method` (i.e. `:get`, `:post`, etc.), letting you restrict which methods may be used to access the route:

> ```
> map.connect 'post/:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show',
>             :conditions => { :method => :get }
> ```

`:requirements`, on the other hand, lets you specify a regular expression that the parameter must match, e.g. if the parameter is a postal code you can give it a regular expression that only matches postal codes:

> ```
> map.geocode 'geocode/:postalcode', :controller => 'geocode',
>             :action => 'show', :requirements => { :postalcode => /\d{5}(-\d{4})?/ }
> ```

(You can even drop `:requirements` and use this shorter form:)

> ```
> map.geocode 'geocode/:postalcode', :controller => 'geocode',
>             :action => 'show', :postalcode => /\d{5}(-\d{4})?/
> ```

Look under "Route conditions" and "Regular Expressions and parameters" in [ActionController::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html), from which I stole the above examples.